# ruby assign array to another variable and when delete element from that assign variable deleted on original array also

Tags: arrays, ruby

Am facing strange issue. I have an array below.

```
irb(main):007:0> original_array = []
=> []
irb(main):008:0> original_array.push("word1")
=> ["word1"]
irb(main):009:0> original_array.push("word2")
=> ["word1", "word2"]
irb(main):010:0> puts "#{original_array.inspect}"
["word1", "word2"]
=> nil
irb(main):011:0>
```

So when I have assigned this array to another array variable,

```
irb(main):011:0> assigned_array = []
=> []
irb(main):012:0> assigned_array = original_array
=> ["word1", "word2"]
irb(main):013:0>
irb(main):014:0> puts "#{assigned_array.inspect}"
["word1", "word2"]
=> nil
irb(main):015:0>
```

Now when I delete en element from the assigned_array its deleting from the original array also.

```
irb(main):015:0> assigned_array.delete("word2")
=> "word2"
irb(main):016:0> puts "#{assigned_array.inspect}"
["word1"]
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> puts "#{original_array.inspect}"
["word1"]
=> nil
```

Am not sure whether its the actual behavior of ruby. If so then is there any way to assign the original_array to assigned_array variable when I delete an element from assigned_array which shouldn't delete from original_array?

Comment: Somebody has already answer, I would like to point a single point where you don't have to do that way, that is, `irb(main):011:0> assigned_array = []
=> []
irb(main):012:0> assigned_array = original_array` You don't have to create the array first, because in the second line, you are assigning another array, So first one will be erased. If you understand this, it will deepen your understanding. So you can directly assign an array to any variable which need not to be declared as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes this is intended behavior of ruby. You can copy it by doing `assigned_array = original_array.clone`. Note: this creates a shallow copy (more info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy)

Assigning an non-literal from another non-literal (`a = b`) doesn't copy the contents of the object, just the reference. The result is that both original_array and assigned_array are the same instance of an array, so modifying one modifies the other, since they're the same object.

script example:

```
original_array = ["word1", "word2"]
puts original_array.inspect #=> ["word1", "word2"]
assigned_array = original_array.clone
assigned_array.delete("word2")
puts assigned_array.inspect #=> ["word1"]
puts original_array.inspect #=> ["word1", "word2"]
```

Comment: Thank for clarification @Philip

Comment: This is the behavior of almost all programming languages, except PHP :)